# Show loader before observable starts

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

Is there a way in which we can show a loader before an observable is executed and hide the loader after it has executed completely.

Below is my observable.

```
 return Observable.interval(60000).switchMap(() =>
            Observable.forkJoin(
                self.http.get(url1, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                self.http.get(url2, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                self.http.get(url3, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),                    
            )
        )
```

The subscription is in **another** component

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go full-observable, you first have to decide how to encode the loading state. You can do so by using a value which you know is invalid (like `null` or `undefined`). Alternatively, you can wrap your model with an object like `{isLoading: boolean, data: T}`, and as long as `isLoading` is `true`, `data` can be `undefined` and you'll know never to access it, so the code won't break. The first option is quicker to do in the beginning, but the second one is more scalable on the long run, since you can encode more states, such as "error" or "empty".

Now you utilize the `startWith` operator.

```
data$ = getData().startWith(null).subscribe(data => { this.data =  data })
```

In your template, you just conditionally show the spinner:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data else loading">
  {{ data | json }}
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  <my-spinner></my-spinner>
</ng-template>
```